# Setup securityContext inside kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-security, kubernetes-deployment

I'm using a nfs mounted volume in my deployments.
I need to give it the fsGroup like below:

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 1000
  runAsGroup: 3000
  fsGroup: 2000
```

Is there a way to make this on the deployment manifest?
As I can see on the documentation I can set the securitycontext in the pod yaml only.

Comment: deployment got a  pod template, that is the same as the pod spec. You can set security context there.

Comment: Do you mean under spec.containers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `securityContext` in `Deployment` in the same way you use it inside `Pod`.

Like it was already suggested by placing it under `template.spec`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      securityContext:
          runAsUser: 2000
          runAsGroup: 3000
          fsGroup: 2000
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: busybox
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        command: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 1h" ]
```

And you can test it:

```
$ kubectl exec -it test-deployment-54d954d7f-2b582  sh
/ $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 2000      0:00 sleep 1h
    6 2000      0:00 sh
   11 2000      0:00 ps
/ $ whoami
whoami: unknown uid 200
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing this exact issue right now (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484063/how-to-properly-setup-hostpath-persistent-volume-on-minikube). I can't get this to work in my Deployment. When trying your answer, my pod gets stuck on a `CrashLoopBackOff` error. Checking the logs via `kubectl logs pod/<pod id>` shows this error:
/sbin/runit-wrapper: line 5: can't create /env: Permission denied. I need help badly, please!