# How to properly setup hostPath persistent volume on Minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, lumen, kubernetes-deployment

I'm currently working on a Lumen project where we are using Minikube as our dev environment. Our host machine's `/Users/development/<project name>` is mounted at `/var/www/html` and is working fine.
However, I'm facing this Storage issue where file writes are not working in the `/var/www/html/storage/framework` due to the fact that the entire `/var/www/html` directory has the **1001:1001** ownership.

This is my deployment spec:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apiserver
  namespace: development
  labels:
    app: sample-app-name
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-app-name
      tier: apiserver
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-app-name
        tier: apiserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php-app
        image: my-image:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/var/www/html"
            name: host-mount
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockercred
      volumes:
      - name: host-mount
        hostPath:
          path: "/Users/development/<app directory>"
```

I tried moving the persistent volume onto its own separate file, and had created a pvc, but still, it's not working.
I also tried multiple ways on how to change the directory permissions using both init containers and security context, but it still the permissions are always set to **1001:1001*
I'm really desperate here, so any help would be appreciated.

Host specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Minikube Version: v0.30.0
- Kubectl Client Version: Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.2", GitCommit:"c97fe5036ef3df2967d086711e6c0c405941e14b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T19:18:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
- Kubectl Server Version: Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
- Virtualbox Version: 5.2.34 r133893 (Qt5.9.5)

**EDIT:** (Here's docker file of the image i'm using in the Deployment)

```
FROM phpearth/php:7.1-nginx

RUN apk add --no-cache php7.1-redis php7.1-pdo php7.1-pdo_pgsql php7.1-xdebug composer bash

COPY ./nginx-default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.1/conf.d/xdebug.ini
COPY ./www.conf /etc/php/7.1/php-fpm.d/www.conf
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/storage/import
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/storage/import/files
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/storage/import/templates
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/storage/logs
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/storage/framework/sessions
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/storage/framework/views
RUN touch /var/www/storage/logs/lumen.log
RUN chown -Rf 1000:1000 /var/www/
# Install the blackfire client
RUN version=$(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.PHP_MINOR_VERSION;") \
    && curl -A "Docker" -o /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz -D - -L -s http://packages.blackfire.io/binaries/blackfire-php/1.23.1/blackfire-php-alpine_amd64-php-71.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/blackfire \
    && tar zxpf /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz -C /tmp/blackfire \
    && mv /tmp/blackfire/blackfire-*.so $(php -r "echo ini_get('extension_dir');")/blackfire.so \
    && printf "extension=blackfire.so\nblackfire.agent_socket=tcp://blackfire:8707\n" > /etc/php/7.1/conf.d/blackfire.ini \
    && rm -rf /tmp/blackfire /tmp/blackfire-probe.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this wasn't a mounting issue. I kept blaming the `hostPath` mount
because when I try running `ls -lah` on */var/www*, it kept showing the *html* directory's permissions as **1001:1001** instead of www-data.

In the end, it was PHP's user that wasn't running on the correct UID.
Dumping `posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())` shows the following result:

```
array:7 [
  "name" => "www-data"
  "passwd" => "x"
  "uid" => 82
  "gid" => 82
  "gecos" => "www-data"
  "dir" => "/var/www"
  "shell" => "/sbin/nologin"
]
```

But after adding this line in my Dockerfile:
`RUN apk add shadow && usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data`, it now shows this:

```
array:7 [
  "name" => "www-data"
  "passwd" => "x"
  "uid" => 1000
  "gid" => 1000
  "gecos" => "www-data"
  "dir" => "/var/www"
  "shell" => "/sbin/nologin"
]
```

I'm not having any permission issues now on my APIs.

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote I understand that your host machine's `/Users/development/<project name>` is mounted at `/var/www/html` in your VM so in kubernetes you should reference it with

```
volumes:
  - name: host-mount
    hostPath:
       path: "/var/www/html"
```

and also specifying security context like following should make it work

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1001
    runAsGroup: 1001
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: I just tried this, but still, it didn't work and my pod's status became Error. `kubectl logs pod/<pod id>` return this:
_/sbin/runit-wrapper: line 5: can't create /env: Permission denied_

By the way, I added my Dockerfile to see if it helps.

Comment: I can see that ` /sbin/runit-wrapper` is trying to create `/env` in the root tree so it needs root permissions to write to it, so modifying `securityContext` won't work because the container needs to start as root to be able to modify these files. I also noticed that you are using kubernetes v1.10 which is no longer supported version. Anyway try changing files owner on your host: `chown 82:82 -R /Users/development/<project name>`, this might not be the best solution but at least will make us sure what's the issue.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve by running `RUN chown -Rf 1000:1000 /var/www/` in you dockerfile as there is no user of `id=1000` in the container?

Comment: Hi @HelloWorld, thank you so much for your assistance. I feel bad that this is very far from a Kubernetes issue. Please see my posted answer